# How do I determine what video/multimedia technologies used by specific web sites might cause issues with a monitor?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

This question is related to troubleshooting an [issue with a monitor](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/U3415W-goes-black-temporarily-video-enabled-websites/m-p/7785143) where it consistently loses its connection to my laptop for a few seconds when certain specific web sites are visited but not others. I'd like to determine what specific video/multimedia technologies are used by the desktop versions of these web sites:

- Netflix (web player)
- Prime Video (web player)
- https://www.totalwine.com (oddly enough. every page view)

But NOT:

- https://www.youtube.com
- https://www.cnn.com/videos
- https://www.espn.com/videos

Do those first 3 examples have something in common that the others don't? In the cases of Netflix and Prime Video, perhaps something with streaming big, HD content is the problem. But Total Wine?? Not sure if it's related, but exactly the same symptom.

I would welcome any suggestions to check other specific sites or use specific tools. Unfortunately the monitor is out of warranty (barely) and I wasn't able to get much help from the Dell community. (Drivers, etc are all up to date as detailed [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/U3415W-goes-black-temporarily-video-enabled-websites/m-p/7785143).) Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a strange problem.  However, it is not your monitor that is the issue.  Most likely, this is a graphics card/graphics driver issue.  Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: @Keltari Well isn't this interesting. I could have sworn I've tried this in multiple browsers but latest Firefox appears to do just fine with totalwine.com. I do have more privacy features enabled and fewer extensions, so I suppose it's possible it's blocking something that Chrome isn't.

Comment: Also, the reasons I strongly suspected the monitor is that the exact same issue happened with an older laptop, and a coworker with the same model monitor and different laptop can also repro.